# How to access functions in injected .js files from evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Is it possible to reference functions in an embedded JavaScript file, when calling `page.evaluate()` using PhantomJS?

e.g. I would like to call a function `someFunctionInMyJs` included in the file my.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.injectJs('my.js')
page.open('http://...', function() {
    var x = page.evaluate(function() {
       var y = someFunctionInMyJs();
       return y;
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Is that possible/are there alternative approaches?

my.js looks like this:

```
function someFunctionInMyJs() {
    return 'Hi there!';
}
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: someFunctionInMyJs
```

my.js lies in the folder where I'm invoking PhantomJS.

Comment: Your example my.js contains a syntax error. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) events. Maybe there are errors. If there are no errors, you could try to explicitly define the function as `window.someFunctionInMyJs = function(){...}`.

Comment: @Artjom Thanks: I've fixed the JS using http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html but I still can't get the function to be recognised. Could you perhaps paste in an answer an example of the "window." usage below? I've tried the example http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html but that has problems too. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you inject a script into the page which is about:blank at this point and then open your intended page. You need to inject your script inside of the `page.open` callback. You will have to do this every time you navigate to another page.

```js
page.open('http://...', function() {
    page.injectJs('my.js')
    var x = page.evaluate(function() {
       var y = someFunctionInMyJs();
       return y;
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

You can also try to inject (`injectJs`) your script from through the [`page.onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html) handler, if your script for example exchanges the implementation of XMLHttpRequest.

If this still doesn't work, it is possible that your function isn't global in which case you have to make it so. Edit my.js to define your function as

```js
window.someFunctionInMyJs = function() {
    return 'Hi there!';
};
```